# Property without getter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

How can I declare a property with a custom setter, but without getter in Kotlin?
In [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) for example they do it like this:

```
var myProperty: Type
    @Deprecated(AnkoInternals.NO_GETTER, level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR) 
    get() = AnkoInternals.noGetter()
    set(value) { field = value; /* setter logic */ }
```

But it looks a bit hacky to me. Is this a right way to do so? If yes, then what about the case when a project doesn't have Anko dependency?

P.S. Let me be clear - I want to have no getter at all, rather than private getter

Comment: I thought objects were immutable in Kotlin.  I'm new to the language, so I'm not sure.  It's a more functional style, is it not?  No, I'm wrong: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Private getter and public setter for a Kotlin property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243085/private-getter-and-public-setter-for-a-kotlin-property)

Comment: @zsmb13, nope, I don't intend to have a private getter, but rather no getter at all

Comment: Still the same question, you're looking for a write-only property. Deprecating the setter is still the best way to go for this use case.

Comment: @duffymo, I'm new as well, but I'm not sure whether properties are a feature of functional programming

Comment: Functional programming means functions and immutable objects.  That's the beauty of it: Everything is inherently thread safe and parallelizable.

Comment: Kotlin allows programming in procedural, object-oriented, and functional styles, you can mix them without any restrictions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deprecating the getter is still the only way to get the effect.

You don't need an Anko dependency, just use the `@Deprecated` annotation with an appropriate `level`.

Answer (score 1):

voddan's answer was great, but I can also supplement it with how I implemented it:

```kotlin
@get:Deprecated(message = "no.", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
lateinit var property: Any
```

here I use the `lateinit` modifier and the `@Deprecated` annotation for the getter.